# Excluding field from _source causes aggregation to not work

Tags: elasticsearch, source-filter

We're using Elasticsearch 1.7.2 and trying to use the "include/exclude from `_source`" feature as it's described here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html

We have a field `types` that's 'pretty' and that we would like to return to the client but it's not well suited to aggregations, and a field `types_int` (and also a `types_string` but that's not relevant now) that's 'ugly' but optimized for search/aggregations which we don't want to return to the client but that we want to aggregate/filter on.

The field `types_int` doesn't need to be stored anywhere, it just needs to be indexed. We don't want to waste bandwidth in returning it to the client either, so we don't want to include it in `_source`.

The mapping for it looks like this:

```
"types_int": {
  "type": "nested",
  "properties": {
     "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
     },
     "value_int": {
        "type": "integer"
     }
  }
}
```

However, after we add the exclude, our filters/aggregations on it stop working.

The excludes looks like this:

```
"_source": {
   "excludes": [
      "types_int"
   ]
}
```

Without that in the mapping, everything works fine.

An example of a filter:

```
POST my_index/my_type/_search
{
   "filter": {
      "nested": {
         "path": "types_int",
         "filter": {
            "term": {
               "types_int.name": "<something>"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Again, removing the `excludes` and everything works fine.

Thinking it might have something to do with nested types, since they're separate documents and all and perhaps handled differently from normal fields, I added an exclude mapping for a 'normal' value type field and then my filter *also* stopped working.

```
 "publication": {
    "type": "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
 }

 "_source": {
     "excludes": [
        "publication"
     ]
  }
```

So my conclusion is that after you exclude something from `_source`, you can no longer filter on it? Which doesn't make sense to me, so I'm thinking there's something we're doing wrong here. The `_source` include/exclude is just a post-process action that manipulates the string data inside that field, right?

I understand that we can also use source filtering to request specific fields to not be included at query time, but it's simply unnecessary to store it. If anything, I would just like to understand why this doesn't work :)

Comment: This one caught my eye since I had come across it before and just worked around it in the past.  These github issues referenced in https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11116 might be worth a read since there's a discussion about the future of these features I think.